# value of property in nested object JS

Tags: javascript, object, properties, nested

`claimReservation` function. It should:

1. If the reservation exists and is unclaimed, welcome the user (use
   alert).
2. If the reservation exists and is already claimed, inform the user
   about the situation (use alert).
3. If there is no reservation, tell the user there is nothing under
   their name (user alert).

Use 'Bob' and 'Ted' to test your code.

***my code*** :

```
var reservations = {
  'Bob': { claimed: false },
  'Ted': { claimed: true }
}

var name = prompt('Please enter the name for your reservation');

var claimReservation = function (name) {
  if(reservations.claimed == "false"){
alert("Welcome")
  }
  else if(reservations.name.claimed == "true"){
alert("You have a problem bruh!")
  }
  else{
     alert("No reservation by that name bruh")
  }
 }

claimReservation("Leeann");
claimReservation("Bob");
claimReservation("Ted")
`
```

Comment: Updated the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to use a prompt to get the name and then reference "name" as the passed in variable to the function? Please see the updated code and let me know if you have any questions.

```js
var reservations_ = {
  'Bob': {
    'claimed': false
  },
  'Ted': {
    'claimed': true
  }
};


var claimReservation = function(name) {
  if (reservations_.hasOwnProperty(name) === false) {
    alert("No reservation by that name bruh");
    return;
  }
  if (reservations_[name].claimed === false) {
    alert("Welcome " + name);
  } else if (reservations_[name].claimed === true) {
    alert(name + ", you have a problem bruh!");
  }
};


claimReservation("Leeann");
claimReservation("Bob");
claimReservation("Ted");

var name = prompt('Please enter the name for your reservation');
claimReservation(name);
```